# 6281 Event failure

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, logging

In our network, we are receiving constant event failures in this category. Can somebody explain what may be the reason?

```
Event 6281 occurred at 02-04-2021 10:07:16.
Date Time: 02-04-2021 10:07:16
Event Source: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Event Category: 12290
Event Type: Information
Event ID: 6281
Event Log Name: HardwareEvents
User: N/A
Computer: xxxxxx
Description:
Code Integrity determined that the page hashes of an image file are not valid. The file could be improperly signed without page hashes or corrupt due to unauthorized modification. The invalid hashes could indicate a potential disk device error.

File Name: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\aepic.dll
Event Parameters:
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\aepic.dll
%String2%
%String3%
```